# How to do Jasmine unit test to a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am very new to Typescript and Jasmine Unit testing.
I ran the code coverage, and I need to test this function. How do I do this?

```
 public amountValidator(formControl: AbstractControl): any {
    if (formControl.value) {
        const amount: number = CurrencyUtility.parseLocaleNumber(formControl.value);
        if (amount > 0) {
            return undefined;
        } else if (amount <= 0 || isNaN(amount)) {
            return { isInvalid: true };
        }

    }

    return { isRequired: true };
}
```

Comment: You should add the code that you have already tried. How to write unit tests is a very subjective question.
This will help you: https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-unit-testing-jasmine-karma-step-by-step-e3376d110ab4

Comment: Share your efforts as well